# Why are only certain javascript functions working in the HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I think I might have formatted some of my javascript functions wrong- I'm new to html. Only one of them works. They're all the script tag, but the full program is included. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>State Tax Calculator</title>

  <body>
    <form name="stateSelect">
      <!sets value to options, tax rate to state>
      Select which state you are purchasing from:
            <select id="stateOptions" onchange="showData()">
            <option value='.04'>Alabama</option>
            <option value='0'>Alaska</option>
            <option value='.0560'>Arizona</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <p id="firstP">&nbsp;</p>
    <script>

    function showData() {
        //extracts value from option selected
        var theSelect = stateSelect.stateOptions;
        var firstP = document.getElementById('firstP');
        firstP.innerHTML = ('Your state retail tax rate is: ' +
                          theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value * 100 + '%');
    }

    function askPrice() {
      //asks the user for the price of their item
      var price = Window.prompt("What's the price of your retail item?","0");
          if (person == null || person == "") {
            txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
          }
      var num1 = parseInt(price);
    }

    function finalCost(){
      //multiplies the original price with the state tax rate to get final cost
      return askPrice * theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Only the function showData is working- did I format the other functions wrong? Should they be in a separate script tag? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ı solved and updated. Check it.

Comment: Html comments should look like this: <!--sets value to options, tax rate to state--> with the hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't run the askPrice and finalCost functions ? These functions need to work depending on a particular function, but you have not defined them in the page.

I think that's what you want to do. I put all the functions under one function.

Now, when you make changes on the selectbox, it receives price information from the user and displays the change according to the price information on the screen.

Since you haven't exactly stated what you want, that's all I can do. If you understand your logic,you make the necessary arrangements.

```
let firstP = document.getElementById('firstP');
function showData() {
    let theSelect = stateSelect.stateOptions;
    let selectValue = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    let getUserPrice = window.prompt("What's the price of your retail item?","0");
    firstP.innerHTML = 'Your state retail tax rate is:' + (getUserPrice * parseFloat(selectValue)) + "%"

}
```

Comment: thank you, i appreciate it! ;') i'm sorry if i wasn't too specific, i'm pretty new at this haha.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't call these functions, classic mistake.
Once you have defined the functions, you still need to specify "When to run" them, AKA "call" them.

the reason `showData()` works fine is because you have specified to call it whenever `stateselect` is changed. Until you set similar scenarios for your other functions, I'm afraid they won't run.